# How to solve this recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, math, recursion, recurrence

I have a recurrence like this `f(n)=(2*f(n-1)+2*f(n-2))%10007;`

Now for a particular n i need to find:

```
g(n)=(f(n)f(0)+f(n-1)f(1)+....+f(0)f(n))%10007.
```

For example if n=3,

```
g(3)=(f(3)f(0)+f(2)f(1)+f(1)f(2)+f(0)f(3))%10007.
```

`n` can be as large as 10^9. I can find value of `f(n)` using matrix exponent in `log(n)` but i cant figure out how to get `g(n)`.

(I need this to solve a problem from [amritapuri 2008 regional](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=310&page=show_problem&problem=2333)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.


Comment: @DavidEisenstat I disagree. It is about solving a mathematical problem using a program. It is very much in-topic.

Comment: @David Eisenstat: "matrix exponentiation" is a programming topic and this is a problem from a programming contest.

Comment: I happen to know how to solve it, and it's much more of a combinatorics problem than an algorithms problem.

Comment: There is a relatively simple formula for f(n).  Look up why the golden ratio is special to the Fibonacci sequence, and then alter that formula with the number special to this recurrence.

Comment: @user1125600 For large `n` values - you are going to get a huge numerical error for using the close formula with the golden ratio, since you cannot represent it exactly using floating point arithmetics.

Comment: I should have mentioned that i need answer modulo 10007, i edited the post. @Amit: My main concern is with g(n), f(n) can be solved easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### BACKGROUND

The original question is about how to tile a 2*n rectangle with 4 types of tiles.

What is unusual is that the tiling must divide into two pieces.

### HINT 1

However, you can also consider this as a way of tiling this with the original 4 tiles coloured red, and another set of 4 tiles coloured blue such that the final board has a red side and a blue side.

### HINT 2

Let f(n) be the number of ways of tiling a 2*n rectangle with just red tiles, and h(n) be the number of ways of tiling a 2*n rectangle with 0 or more columns of red tiles followed by 1 or more columns of blue tiles.

### HINT 3

You can now find a simple matrix multiplication that gives the next values of h and f in terms of their two previous values and use the standard matrix power exponentiation to find the final values.

### EXAMPLE CODE

Here is a Python demonstration that this formula gives the same answer as the original summation.

```
def f(n):
    """Number of ways to tile 2*n board with red tiles"""
    if n<0: return 0
    if n==0: return 1
    return 2*f(n-1)+2*f(n-2)

def g_orig(n):
    """Number of ways to tile 2*n board in two halves"""
    return sum(f(k)*f(n-k) for k in range(n+1))

def h(n):
    """Number of ways to tile 2*n board with red tiles and at least one column of blue tiles"""
    if n<1: return 0
    # Consider placing one column of blue tiles (either 2*1 or 2 1*1)
    t=2*(f(n-1)+h(n-1))
    # Also consider placing two columns of blue tiles (either a 2*2 or L shaped and a 1*1)
    t+=2*(f(n-2)+h(n-2))
    return t

def g(n):
    return f(n)+h(n)

for n in range(10):
    print n,g_orig(n),g(n)
```

Comment: What formula did you find for `g` in terms of its two previous values?

Comment: Note that g depends on the previous 2 values of g AND the previous 2 values of f.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about 10007 for a second.

Let `F(x)=sum(f(n)*x^n)`. Then `F(x)=(f(0)+x*(f(1)-2f(0))/(1-2x-2x^2)`.

Let `G(x)=sum(g(n)*x^n)`. Then `G(x)=F(x)^2`.

Thus the problem is reduced to finding the coefficient of a series (modulo 10007).

Comment: I don't get it... the OP doesn't even say what `f(0)` is. What if it's 0? Doesn't really fit then.

Comment: No it's not. If `f(1) = 1`, the other values will not be 0.

Comment: f(n) is presumably intended to be the number of ways to tile 2 x n ignoring where the split is, so f(0) = 1 and f(1) = 2.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - I still don't get it. Then `F(1) = 1 / 3`, which doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.../(1-2x-2x^2)`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: yes, sure, sorry

Comment: Off-Topic but H.S. Wilf has a link to his famous "generatingfunctionology" book in pdf: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html. You find the explaination of G(x) = F(x) in page 36, rule 3.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that the sequence `f(n) mod 10007` has a period of 10007, i.e. `f(n) mod 10007 = f(n + 10007) mod 10007`. So all you need to do is simply (1) calculate `f(0 .. n - 1) mod 10007`, (2) calculate `f(n - k)f(k) mod 10007` for `0 <= k < 10007`, and then (3) sum them up according to your equation. You don't even need the power exponentiation method to calculate `f(n)`.